# How to configure Ubuntu server netplan sriov vlan tagged vf?

Tags: server, 20.04, netplan, interface, vlan

How do I configure vlan tags on specific SR-IOV vf interfaces with netplan?
I tried the following to prove that vlan tags work on a regular interface:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp94s0f2:
            mtu: 1500
    vlans:
        enp94s0f2.1014:
            id: 1014
            link: ens124
            mtu: 1500
```

This works, vlan interface `enp94s0f2.1014@enp94s0f2` appears.

Then I tried configuring SR-IOV VF interfaces to make sure they work.

```
network:
    ethernets:
        virtual-function-count: 1
        enp94s0f2:
            mtu: 1500
        enp94s0f2v0:
            link: enp94s0f2
            mtu: 1500
```

This works, virtual function interface `enp94s0f2v0` appears.

However when I try to combine the two it does not work, only the vf appears.

```
network:
    ethernets:
        virtual-function-count: 1
        enp94s0f2:
            mtu: 1500
        enp94s0f2v0:
            link: enp94s0f2
            mtu: 1500
    vlans:
        enp94s0f2v0.1014:
            id: 1014
            link: enp94s0f2v0
            mtu: 1500
```

Reading the examples for netplan [here](https://netplan.io/examples/#attaching-vlans-to-network-interfaces) I found nothing on attaching vlans to sriov interfaces.

There looks to be a PR that was merged in 2020 for netplan to attach vlans to sriov interfaces, but its not clear how this works to me, can someone explain? Maybe I have my syntax wrong: [Here is a link.](https://github.com/canonical/netplan/pull/129)

I need `enp94s0f2v0.1014@enp94s0f2v0` to be created. How can I accomplish this?
Also, while we are in the world of SR-IOV and VLANs, how do I get netplan to clean its self up if I remove a VF or a VLAN? any time I create a VF or VLAN with netplan, then adjust my netplan config to remove it, netplan refuses to clean itself up, I have to literally reboot the host.

**EDIT**
My original post was using "eth124". That was me masking my actual port names from the public. The actual port names were longer. I updated them to be "enp94s0f2", this update is important as the problem is related to the length of the interface names.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
The problem was due to the length of the sub interface names I was supplying.

`enp94s0f2v0.1014` is too long. Netplan gives no warning to this, the interface just does not appear so there was no way to tell why this was happening. Seems the limit in characters is 15. I was providing 16.

Here is the configuration that worked for me:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        virtual-function-count: 1
        enp94s0f2:
            mtu: 1500
        enp94s0f2v0:
            link: enp94s0f2
            mtu: 1500
    vlans:
        e94s0f-2v0.1014:
            id: 1014
            link: enp94s0f2v0
            mtu: 1500
```

notice how `e94s0f-2v0.1014` is shorter than `enp94s0f2v0.1014` by one character.

**EDIT**
So, after more testing, the sub interface refuses to keep the vlan tags. I make sure to check `ip link` that the sriov interface was not already tagging, (which it is not). In the end, netplan will create the sub interface, but its useless.
Workaround, dont use netplan to create sub interfaces off a VF. I still use netplan to create the VFs, that works. Need to apply vlan tag to the SR-IOV interface with `ip link`, then apply an ip address directly onto the SR-IOV VF with `ip a`, like this:

```
ip link set dev enp94s0f2 vf 0 vlan 1014
ip addr add 172.0.14.1/24 dev enp94s0f2v0
ip link set dev enp94s0f2v0 up
```

You know its set up correctly if you check `ip -br a`, and see an ip address on your vf. as well as `ip link`, the pf should show the vf with the vlan tag applied.

Its a shame, I like using netplan but it just refuses to work properly in this circumstance.